# JQuery DataTable pagination is not displaying when using If else condition in my view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, datatables

My DataTable pagination works fine, but when i put in a @if else condition in my View, the pagination goes away.

In my Controller, I am setting the TempData based on a condition like this:

```
if (userVml[0].Role.RoleName == "RoleUser")
  {
     TempData["UserRole"] = userVml[0].Role.RoleName;
     return View("UserSearch");
  }
```

and in my View, I am implementing this @if else condition based on the role, like this:

```
 @if (TempData["UserRole"].ToString() == "RoleUser")
    {
        @*<th>
         @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NoKnownApproval)
        </th>*@
    }
   else
    {
        <th>
           @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NoKnownApproval)
        </th>
     }
```

Any pointers on where to look why my pagination is stripping ?

Answer (score 0):

Corrected my jquery statements by removing the explicit declaration of the width column and it resolved the pagination issue.